# NLog: Does the FormControl target really exist?

Tags: nlog

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FormControl-target), NLog offers a `FormControl` target that will write log messages into the `Text` property of a control on a Windows Form.  However, when I add a `FormControl` target to my configuration, I get an exception telling me that no target exists named "FormControl".  I did download the `NLog.Windows.Forms` package and include a reference to the DLL in my project.

Here's the configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwExceptions="true">

  <!-- 
  See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file 
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
  <targets>
    <!--
    <target xsi:type="File" name="FileTarget" fileName="${basedir}/NLogger_4_1_2.log"
            layout="${date} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
    -->
    <target name="AsyncTarget" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="5000" overflowAction="Discard">
      <target xsi:type="File" name="FileTarget1" fileName="${basedir}/NLogger_4_1_2.log"
              layout="${date} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
    </target>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ReportTarget" fileName="${basedir}/NLogger_4_1_2_report.log"
            layout="${date} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
    <target xsi:type="FormControl"
            name="FormControlTarget"
            layout="${message}"
            append="true"
            controlName="TextBox1"
            formName="Form1" />

  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="FileLogger" minlevel="Trace"
            writeTo="AsyncTarget" />
    <logger name="ReportLogger" minlevel="Trace"
            writeTo="ReportTarget" />
    <logger name="FormLogger" minlevel="Trace"
            writeTo="FormControlTarget" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: This works as expected for me, with the caveat that `TextBox1` needed to be changed to `textBox1` to match the default name that VS2015 gave it.

Answer (score 3):

I found this question in 2022 trying to get this working in VS2022. The answer is you need  the NLog.Windows.Forms NuGet package installed.

And it is recommended to update NLog.config to include NLog.Windows.Forms-assembly in `<extensions>`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog>
  <extensions> 
    <add assembly="NLog.Windows.Forms"/> 
  </extensions> 

  ...
</nlog>
```